# Lipschitz constants of projections

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, projective-geometry

Consider two compact sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume that the projection mappings $P_A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow A$, $P_B : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow B$ have Lipschitz constant $1$ and $L$, respectively.

What is the Lipschitz constant of the projection mapping $P_{A \cap B}$?

Comment: Just an idea, but $\min \{ 1,L \}$ ?

Comment: What does projection mapping mean?

Comment: $P_A(x) := \arg \min_{ y \in A } \left\| x-y\right\| $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nearest point projection onto a closed subset  $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ is single-valued if and only if $E$ is convex*. In this case, the Lipschitz constant is equal to $1$.

If $E$ is not convex, there is at least one point $x\in \mathbb R^n$ for which $\min_{y\in E}\|x-y\|$ is attained at more than one point. We could try to discuss the continuity of $P_E$ as a multivalued map, using the Hausdorff metric. But this turns out to be futile: since the set of points with unique nearest point projection is dense, an arbitrarily small perturbation of $x$ can change $P_E(x)$ to a singleton. Thus, $p_E$ is discontinuous when $E$ is not convex.

Therefore, under your assumptions we can say that $A$ and $B$ are convex, $L=1$, and since $A\cap B$ is also convex, $P_{A\cap B}$ is $1$-Lipschitz as well.

---

(*) in a Hilbert space, convexity still implies that the nearest point projection is single-valued, but the converse is an open problem (stated, e.g., on page 67 of *Nonlinear Functional Analysis* by Deimling).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My set $B$ is non-convex, in particular the product of circumferences: $B = \partial C \times \partial C \cdots \times \partial C$ ($n/2$ times).

Now if I exclude a ball of radius $\epsilon$ around the origin, I guess that $P_B$ is Lipschitz with $L = 2/\epsilon$ or so.

What about $P_{A \cap B}$ then?

Comment: @Adam Still does not work. Let $B$ be the circle, for simplicity. Let $A$ be a square such that $B\setminus A$ is a small arc of $B$. Then the projection onto $A\cap B$ is discontinuous at the midpoint of said arc.

Comment: Good catch, thanks.